# Applying security updates to dependencies installed with Maven

Tags: java, security, maven

We have a web application that is implemented in Java.  It uses Maven to install various dependencies such as JavaMail, Gson, and so on.

Unfortunately, deploying and maintaining the project is a nuisance.  We need to be aware that any of those dependencies might issue a security update, which means checking regularly for new versions.  To make matters worse, we can't see any way that Maven can distinguish security fixes from other new releases.  This means that we end up doing needless updates, which is a waste of time and could break something.

The server itself runs Ubuntu, and the situation there is far better.  Apt installs urgent updates, but everything else waits until the next Ubuntu release.  That's ideal because it gives us a stable but secure platform that we can build on.

Is there any way of making Maven more like Apt, so we can install security fixes but nothing else?  If not, I'd be interested to know what strategies other people use for updating deployed web applications.

(We know about the maven-dependency-plugin.  This plugin helps, because it can automatically find and update any dependencies which have newer versions.  Unfortunately it can't distinguish security updates from normal feature releases, so we end up updating when we don't strictly need to.)

Comment: There really isn't any metadata within the POM itself that specifies that an update is a security update. Without making guesses and parsing changelogs using a natural language parser there really is no way to tell, as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks—it's helpful to know we're doing the best we can, at least!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did come up with a partial solution to this problem, but it doesn't use Maven directly.  I implemented a script which scans the [NVD database](https://nvd.nist.gov/) for new security exposures relating to products we are using.  Every morning I get any new ones emailed to me, and I can decide whether they justify an update to our web application.

The downside of this approach is that smaller projects don't always issue CVE numbers for their vulnerabilities.  We have to restrict ourselves to products that have a significant following, are backed by a large vendor, or have previously demonstrated a willingness to take part in the CVE process.